# Android Studio not picking up AutoParcelGson (AutoValue) classes from Java module

Tags: android, android-studio, apt, auto-value

I've got an Android project with 2 modules, 1 Android and 1 Java, I'm using the AutoParcelGson AutoValue fork in both modules, and they work fine for generating classes and the build will run, however in Android Studio it only resolves the classes from the Android module (that is using the `com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt` plugin), not the Java module (that uses `net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin` plugin)

Is there some configuration that will help me to get these classes to show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me feeling silly... all I had to do was apply the `idea` plugin, as said in the documentation for the gradle-apt-plugin

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
```

at the top of the `build.gradle` file solved it